# Função Router() do Express retorna undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, express.js, módulo-ecmascript

Estou utilizando TypeScript e Express para montar uma API que segue os princípios de Clean Architecture. Separei cada rota da minha aplicação em uma pasta, e então importo todas elas em um arquivo `index.ts`, juntando todas em um único `Router` e exportando o mesmo. Meu problema é que a importação desse arquivo está retornando `undefined`.

Creio que não seja um problema do meu código em si, visto que o TypeScript consegue inferir corretamente o tipo do arquivo importado e não acusa nenhum erro durante o desenvolvimento. O único erro que recebo só acontece ao tentar executar o código:

> TypeError: `app.use()` requires a middleware function

Este é o trecho de código que causa o erro:

```
// expressInstance.ts --> Importado pelo arquivo "server.ts", onde ocorre o "listen"
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import { router } from ".."; // Arquivo com todas as rotas

const expressInstance = express();

expressInstance.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
expressInstance.use(express.json());
expressInstance.use(cors());

expressInstance.use(router); // Linha que causa o erro

export {
    expressInstance
};
```

E este é o código das rotas importadas:

```
// index.ts
import { Router } from "express";
import { userRouter } from "./user.routes";
import { postRouter } from "./post.routes";

const router = Router();
router.use("/user", userRouter);
router.use("/post", postRouter);

export {
    router
};
```

Vi [em uma pergunta aqui do StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465045/express-router-is-returning-undefined) que o retorno de `undefined` ocorria na versão 3 do Express, mas utilizo a versão `4.17.13`, então creio que essa não seja a causa do problema. Aliás, não faço ideia de qual possa ser. Tentei dar um `console.log(router)` no arquivo `index.ts` (antes de ser importado pelo `expressInstance.ts`), mas não deu certo, porque o código sequer chegou a ser executado.

Answer (score -1):

Vendo o código que você forneceu vejo um problema no uso do router do express, você está colocando `router.use` quando o correto seria informar o método http que a rota vai utilizar tipo um `route.get`, `route.post`, etc